# Magento REST API 401 nonce_used

Tags: php, rest, magento

I am creating a connection with a Magento 1.7 webstore via the REST API and I am running into a problem.

The authentication goes fine, but if I request data the connection returns a 401 with the message (OAuth=>DebugInfo) of 'oauth_problem=nonce_used'.

I am requesting the data only once, there is only one REST API connection.

Any ideas? I read through all the usefull messages but could not find the answer. If any one has any clue or a pointer to documentation it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to connect to Magento? The error is valid, the exception is thrown when it's validating that the nonce you've provided hasn't been used before *by you* - it does this by comparing the timestamp of the first time it save your nonce against the timestamp in your payload - if they match, you get this exception. This means that you are in fact using the same nonce more than once, you just may not realise it!

Comment: My feeling may be that when you say "I am creating a connection..." you're talking about the first two legs of the OAuth process, i.e. request a token, then authorize the connection - if you're using the same nonce token anywhere during this process it'll fail. Ensure it's truly random, i.e. something like `md5(microtime())` or similar